# ssh to different server based on user?

Tags: ssh

Is there a simple way to have my router forward ssh logins for certain user names to a different server on my internal network?

For example, ssh router@url would log me in as router on the router and ssh steve@url would log me in as steve on the server.

Also, this needs to be a server side solution because I want it to be simple and easy to use.

Comment: Without MITMing, your router has no idea who you're trying to log in as -- your session is encrypted. Just use different ports for different machines.

Comment: You might try to do something with Host aliases to achieve something _close_ to this. You can set up `url` to attempt to use the steve user account on the server and `url1` can attempt to use the router user account getting you to where you can just type `ssh url` and `ssh url1` respectively. That seems close to what you're wanting to do.

Comment: I've thought of a less than elegant way to do it by creating a steve account on the router with a login script to automatically open an ssh session on the server but I was hoping for something better. I'll probably do this since there are only a few users I need this for right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen anything like what you are asking for, but if I understand your question correctly you want to do what Chris Down said in his comment. Use different ports for different hosts, e.g. port 22 for your server and port 222 for your router. You could then log in like this on the server: `ssh steve@url`, and like this on the router: `ssh -p 222 router@url`.

OpenSSH client has a configuration file that allows you to define aliases. These are handy if you SSH back and forth a lot. Here are two minimal examples (remeber to substitute "url" for your real url):

```
# ~/.ssh/config

Host server
    User steve
    HostName url
    Port 22
Host router
    User router
    HostName url
    Port 222
```

You can now SSH to your server with `ssh server` and to your router with `ssh router`.

If you still insist on making this work on only one port I recommend that you simply SSH into your server and then SSH from the server to the router (or the other way around). 
Alternatively you can create a user named *router* on your server and create a login script that automatically logs on to the router. Depending on your login shell (and the rest of your software, you said nothing about your system) your could do something like this:

```
# Create a new user on the server
useradd -m router -p MyPassWordABC123

# Log in as the new user
su router

# Generate a new SSH key
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "router@server" # You can safely accept the defaults.

# Add your key to authorized keys on the router to be able to log in without password
ssh-copy-id router@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
# Try logging into the router to verify this works

# Add a startup command to your .profile (depends on your shell, .profile works for at least bash)
echo "ssh router@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" >> ~/.profile
```

I should mention that (in my opinion) this is an ugly solution to this problem.

Comment: I agree it's an ugly solution, but it's the only thing I've been able to come up with that does exactly what I want. Do you know if ssh could be set as a user's primary shell?

Comment: Actually, that might be possible. I have never tried anything like that (sounds scary:P) but it might be worth a shot. I am also pretty sure that the usual way of changing login shell, chsh, won't allow you to set a shell that doesn't exist in /etc/shells. You can try to create a script that contains something like `/usr/bin/ssh router@1.2.3.4` and add the path of the script to /etc/shells. The login session will last as long as the SSH process is running (the moment the process finishes you will be logged out).If you actually try this I would love to hear about your results.

Comment: Tried it out last night, worked pretty easily actually. Simply wrote a shell script to ssh $USER@server and specified it as the user's shell in /etc/passwd. Want to figure out a way to put the whole command in/etc/pasdwd but it doesn't pass the arguments